# why fit curve not working

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a mesh with good verts. I want to fit it to the curve. I have set all the parameters. I dont want to have array and adjust the curve. Whats missing why its not taking the turn and making copies.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say you want copies but you say you don't want arrays, which is a bit contradictory... Let say that you want the object to be duplicated all around the curve.

First make sure the origin of your circle is at its center (*Origin To Geometry*) and put your object at the same point.

[image]
[image]

If you want the object to be duplicated around the curve, you need to give it a *Curve* modifier. The *Array* can only duplicate on an axis. The *Fit Curve* option alone won't allow the object to turn around the curve, it will just allow your array to have the same length as the curve. Also, if you need the duplication to happen you need to enable either *Constant* or *Relative* Offset. Let's choose *Relative*. Also enable *Merge* and *First Last*.

[image]

Now give your object a *Curve* modifier so that it follow the curve shape. If the object is not well oriented, rotate it 180° on the right axis.

[image]
[image]

Now you can see that it's not necessarily the result you were expected (?), there's no merging between the copies because of its initial shape (it's already bent), and the object overlaps itself because the *Fit Curve* produces enough copies to be able fit the curve and in that case the curve is a little bit too small to make the first and last copies merge, you can scale it up if you want first and last to stick.

So you probably need to change your object or choose another method.

For the same operation you could also use a *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode) instead of a *Curve* modifier.

And if you didn't want copies, don't use the Array modifier, just the *Curve* or the *Simple Deform*.

Comment: with the above answer i tried but its not working can you plz send file.

Comment: I need precisions, do you want duplications around the curve? do you prefer curve modifier rather than Simple Deform?

Comment: curve modifier .

Comment: ok i've edited, maybe it will answer

Comment: what i was trying. I have mesh and i want to make curve so that it shrinkwrap. So i bend the shape thinking that later array and curve make the curve shape. https://imgur.com/a/ySr4cz6.

Comment: I would do it with the Simple Deform modifier, start with a "flat" shape (or straight, meaning not already bent like yours), use the Shrinkwrap at the end if necessary

Comment: any example how it works.

Comment: you'll easily find some tutorials, for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezg2KlZTgr4

Comment: Did not work for me added a new question here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156434/how-to-bend-and-use-on-mesh

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is the solution or a workaround but the way I would do it is by instancing on a null object with *Object Offset* and rotate the object so to complete the circles.