# How to bend and use on mesh (as shrink wrap)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have mesh and i added array and tried with simple deform method. Did not work for me. With the shrink wrap modifier i tried that also did not work for me. I want to curve the mesh with array modifier and fix (shrinkwrap) on the curve mesh.

[image]

[image]

Always have this same issue to use shrinkwrap on the surface. Any detail answer can fix my issue for ever. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: Did not work is a bit too vague, have you followed some tutorials about array + simple deform? Where didn't it work? Plus I'm not sure you need shrinkrap

Comment: There is no Simpledeform modifier in your file. And you'll need to apply the rotation if you want the Simpledeform to work properly, because by default it will bend on the local Z axis

Comment: @moonboots Yeah all i deleted just kept the clean or simple shape how to start and end with the step. I have always the same issue when and how to bend and shrink the mesh on to it.

Comment: to bend: apply the rotation of your object, create a Simpledeform modifier, put it below the Array, choose the Bend option, choose 360°, it should work.

Comment: Now about the Shrinkwrap, what you could do is create a cylinder around your lamp on the bottom, subdivide it horizontally. Now give your ornement a Surface Deform modifier, choose the cylinder as Target, click on Bind. Back to the cylinder, give it a Shrinkwrap modifier, choose the lamp as Target.

Comment: @moonboots yeah later the shrinkwrap not work on the curve shape. I have rotated and made it curve but i want to fix that shape on the curve.

Comment: my method is not perfect though, I'm going to dig... I think the Mira (or Surface Follow) addon can do it but I've never tried

Comment: what step im missing https://imgur.com/a/f4Q2OMj

Comment: I don't know, please share your file (the one with the cylinder + Mesh Deform modifier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you want to do you could try the *Mira Tools* addon (demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeOEZl01_2I)) or the *Surface Follow* addon (demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1A22jfG-sc&)).

But as your lamp shape is rather simple there are 2 simple tricks, *Mesh Deform* modifier or a second *Curve* modifier (as suggested by Robin Betts):

- Put your ornement around your lamp.
- Create a cylinder around the lamp, subdivide it several times horizontally.

[image]

- Give your ornement a *Mesh Deform* modifier, with the cylinder as *Object*, click *Bind*.
- Select the cylinder, go in *Edit* mode, enable the *Proportional Editing* option, scale and move the horizontal edge loops so that the ornement sticks to your lamp.

[image]

Second approach:

- Deactivate the *Array* and *Curve* modifiers for the moment, create a new *Curve* modifier, put it on the top of the stack, create a curve, use it to make the ornement fit the lamp bottom profile.

[image]

- Apply this modifier to make it easier, bring back the 2 other modifiers (*Array* and *Curve*).

[image]

Comment: i have install the surfacefollow addon cant find in the list 2.79. I have installed the zip file

Comment: I have never installed these 2 addons, try Mira Tools, I've seen a demo for exactly what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I did it using a second curve modifier .. but this is a lot more intuitive

Comment: oh yes, also a good idea, maybe present this option?

Comment: its certainly better as a non destructive solution but it seems a bit tedious to deal with the 2 curve modifiers and the axis orientations, no? Maybe apply this first Curve modifier... EDIT : ok I've edited my answer, too hard to keep 2 Curve modifiers without applying though

Comment: Can you plz share the file i will go through it. Thanks

Comment: I haven't saved it, where do you meet difficulty?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is the final result https://imgur.com/a/1IYX0Dd

Comment: woww very nice!